# Which part is responsible on the animation in this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

this code is from a [jquery countdown counter](https://github.com/Reflejo/jquery-countdown) , I am trying to eliminate the animation (flip) as you can see in the [demo](http://reflejo.github.io/jquery-countdown/), I succeed to remove the main one, but if you notice at the end when a digit is at 0 you see a quick animation back to 9, and I could not figure which part is responsible for that, this is the code again here.

```
/*
 * jquery-countdown plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Martin Conte Mac Donell <Reflejo@gmail.com>
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://docs.jquery.com/License
 *
 */

// Draw digits in given container
var createDigits = function(where, options) {
  var counter = 0;
  // Iterate each startTime digit, if it is not a digit
  // we'll asume that it's a separator
  var mFirstPos, sFirstPos;
  // reset digits and intervals array.
  digits = [];
  intervals = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < options.startTime.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(options.startTime[i]) >= 0) {
      elem = $('<div id="cnt_' + counter + '" class="cntDigit" />').css({
    height: options.digitHeight,
    float: 'left',
    background: 'url(\'' + options.image + '\')',
    width: options.digitWidth
      });

      elem.current = parseInt(options.startTime[i]);
      digits.push(elem);

      margin(counter, -elem.current * options.digitHeight * options.digitImages);

      if (options.continuous === true) {
    digits[counter]._max = function() { return 9; };
      } else {
    // Add max digits, for example, first digit of minutes (mm) has
    // a max of 5. Conditional max is used when the left digit has reach
    // the max. For example second "hours" digit has a conditional max of 4
    switch (options.format[i]) {
      case 'h':
        digits[counter]._max = function(pos, isStart) {
          if (pos % 2 == 0)
        return 2;
          else
        return (isStart) ? 3: 9;
        };
        break;
      case 'd':
        digits[counter]._max = function() { return 9; };
        break;
      case 'm':
        digits[counter]._max = function(pos) {
          if(!mFirstPos) { mFirstPos = pos; } 
          return pos == mFirstPos ? 9 : 5;
        };
        break;
      case 's':
        digits[counter]._max = function(pos) {
          if(!sFirstPos) { sFirstPos = pos; } 
          return pos == sFirstPos ? 9 : 5;
        };
    }
      }

      counter += 1;
    } else {
      elem = $('<div class="cntSeparator"/>').css({float: 'left'})
                         .text(options.startTime[i]);
    }
    where.append(elem)
  }
};

var makeMovement = function(elem, steps, isForward, options) {
  // Stop any other movement over the same digit.
  if (intervals[elem])
    window.clearInterval(intervals[elem]);

  // Move to the initial position (We force that because in chrome
  // there are some scenarios where digits lost sync)
  var initialPos = -(options.digitHeight * options.digitImages *
             digits[elem].current);
  margin(elem, initialPos);
  digits[elem].current = digits[elem].current + ((isForward) ? steps: -steps);

  var x = 0;
  intervals[elem] = setInterval(function() {
    if (x++ === options.digitImages * steps) {
      window.clearInterval(intervals[elem]);
      delete intervals[elem];
      return;
    }

    var diff = isForward ? -options.digitHeight: options.digitHeight;
    margin(elem, initialPos + (x * diff));
  }, options.stepTime / steps);
};

// Set or get element margin
var margin = function(elem, val) {
  if (val !== undefined) {
    digits[elem].margin = val;
    return digits[elem].css({'backgroundPosition': '0 ' + val + 'px'});
  }

  return digits[elem].margin || 0;
};


// Makes the movement. This is done by "digitImages" steps.
var moveDigit = function(elem, options) {
  if (digits[elem].current == 0) {
    // Is there still time left?
    if (elem > 0) {
      var isStart = (digits[elem - 1].current == 0);

      makeMovement(elem, digits[elem]._max(elem, isStart), true, options);
      moveDigit(elem - 1, options);
    } else { // That condition means that we reach the end! 00:00.
      for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    clearInterval(intervals[i]);
    clearInterval(intervals.main);
    margin(i, 0);
      }
      options.timerEnd();
    }
    return;
  }
  makeMovement(elem, 1, false, options);
};



// parses a date of the form hh:mm:ss, for example, where
// ... precision is the same as the format.
var parseRelativeDate = function(form, options) {
  // give the date the values of now by default
  var now = new Date();
  var d = now.getDate();
  var m = now.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = now.getFullYear();
  var h = now.getHours(), mm, s;

  // read in components and render based on format
  var format = options.format;
  var parts = form.split(':');
  if( format.indexOf('dd') == 0 ) {
      d = parts[0];
      parts = parts.slice(1);
      format = format.substr(3);
  }
  if( format.indexOf('hh') == 0 ) {
      h = parts[0];
      parts = parts.slice(1);
      format = format.substr(3);
  }
  if( format.indexOf('mm') == 0 ) {
      mm = parts[0];
      parts = parts.slice(1);
      format = format.substr(3);
  }
  if( format.indexOf('ss') == 0 ) {
      s = parts[0];
      parts = parts.slice(1);
      format = format.substr(3);
  }
  // return our constructed date object
  return new Date([m, d, y].join('/') + ' ' + [h, mm, s].map(pad).join(':') + ' GMT-0900');
};


// convert a date object to the format specified
var formatCompute = function(d, options) {
      var format = options.format;
      var parse = {
    d: d.getUTCDate() - 1,
    h: d.getUTCHours(),
    m: d.getUTCMinutes(),
    s: d.getUTCSeconds()
      };
      return format.replace(/(dd|hh|mm|ss)/g, function($0, form) {
          return pad(parse[form[0]]);
      });
};

// add leading zeros
var pad = function(x){return (1e15+""+x).slice(-2)};

var digits = [];
var intervals = [];
jQuery.fn.countdown = function(userOptions) {
  // Default options
  var options = {
    stepTime: 60,
    // startTime and format MUST follow the same format.
    // also you cannot specify a format unordered (e.g. hh:ss:mm is wrong)
    format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
    startTime: "01:12:32:55",
    digitImages: 6,
    digitWidth: 67,
    digitHeight: 90,
    timerEnd: function(){},
    image: "digits.png",
    continuous: false
  };
  $.extend(options, userOptions);

  // if an endTime is provided...
  if( userOptions.endTime ) {
    // calculate the difference between endTime and present time
    var endDate = userOptions.endTime instanceof Date ? userOptions.endTime : parseRelativeDate(userOptions.endTime, options);
    var diff = endDate.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
    // and set that as the startTime
    userOptions.startTime = formatCompute(new Date(diff), options);
    delete userOptions.endTime;
  }
  $.extend(options, userOptions);
  if (this.length) {
    clearInterval(intervals.main);
    createDigits(this, options);
    intervals.main = setInterval(function(){ moveDigit(digits.length - 1, options); },
                                 1000);
  }
};
```

Comment: Why you people are down voting this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this:

```
 setInterval(function(){ moveDigit(digits.length - 1, options); },
                             1000);
```

your animation has a duration of one second and this runs the function moveDigit()

Comment: do you know how to eliminate that?

Comment: i think only comment this line
 /*intervals.main = setInterval(function(){ moveDigit(digits.length - 1, options); },
                                 1000);*/